# jQuery and for javascript variable scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I'm try to add click event on a Jquery Element using variable "element"..

but the variable into each Event change when I change this variable outside the "click"

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RCZVD)

like that:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var counto = 5;
    for (i = 1; i <= counto; i++) {
        $('.link.' + i).click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('div.output').html(i);
        });
    }
});
```

sorry for my worse english :-)

Thank You

Comment: You're displaying `i` and since you omitted the `var` keyword `i` has the global scope. The value of `i` after your loop is 6.

Comment: @Jonathan: Even if `i` was defined as `var i`, the problem would exist.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: @FelixKling Ah, I see that now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include the script inside a scope:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var counto = 5;
    for (var i = 1; i <= counto; i++) { // do not omit the keyword var
        (function (n) {
            $('.link.' + n).click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('div.output').html(n);
            });
        })(i);
    }
});
```

Otherwise the click function will use the i variable when it's assigned to the last value of the loop(in this case 6).

Comment: The solution is correct, but not the explanation. The event handler already *is* a closure and that is what is causing the problem. The solution is to create a new scope by executing a function, not by using a "closure" (closures don't create scope).